# word problem with ratio proportion

Tags: word-problem

15 employers working 10 hours per day built a 180m long canal  for 12 days. How many days need 32 employers working 8 hours per day to built a 600 m long canal?

Comment: Any thoughts?  How many meters can one worker build in an hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

- How many hours to 15 employees need to dig the 180m canal?
- Therefore, how many hours would just one employee need?
- Therefore, how long a canal does one employee dig in one hour?
- Therefore, how long a canal do 32 employees dig in one hour?
- Therefore, how many hours do 32 employees need to dig 600m of canal?

Answer these questions one by one, tell me where you get stuck.

Comment: @Let'sGo Nicely done. Those are correct answers to questions 1 and 2. Keep going!

Comment: 15 employees need 120 hours to dig the 180 m canal therefore one employee needs 1800 hours to dig a 180 m canal. so in one hour he can dig 1\10 meters  therefore in one hour 32 employees can dig 3.2 meters so to dig a 600 meters canal they will need 187.5 hours.Am i right?

Comment: @Let'sGo Looks good to me!

Comment: but i have another result in my book its 23 and 7\16 days

Comment: @Let'sGo Well yeah, if you work $187.5$ hours, and you work 8 hours each day, then how many days do you work?

Comment: yeah thats right thanks a lot

Comment: @Let'sGo You are welcome. Remember, if the answer is useful to you, you can accept it so the question doesn't appear on te "unanswered" list any more.